# receive data from microphone in scheme

Tags: windows, input, racket, microphone

I want to make voice pitch classfying program in scheme

target platform is windows xp, 7

development environment is DrRacket 5.1

for that, I want to know how to receive data from microphone

could somebody kindly let me know?

any suggestion and advice are also welcome!

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I wanted to accomplish this, I would probably work on extending the PortAudio connection contained in the RSound planet package.  This would almost certainly involve some careful study of the PortAudio interface. Alternatively, you could connect directly to the Windows API's; I hear they're fairly nice. I'm afraid that the short answer is that it's not a simple question of using an existing interface.

Comment: thanks you so much but RSound seems crash very easily there is no alternative rather than windwos API?